# PLSQL more than single row returned issue in ID field

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ora-01427

I have an issue with the query below, in the main **SELECT** the value of 
**ENTITY_ID** cannot be retrieved, as I'm using LIKE I get more than a single result back.
How can I overcome this?
If I place an inner SELECT such as:

```
    (
            SELECT
                SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID
            FROM
                SEC_NN_SERVER_T
            WHERE
                UPPER(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%') )       AS ENTITY_ID,
```

I get the same error:

**"ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row".**

He is the full query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SEC_USER.USR_ID         AS USR_ID,
SEC_USER.USR_FIRST_NAME AS USR_FIRST_NAME,
SEC_USER.USR_LAST_NAME  AS USR_LAST_NAME,
SEC_USER_PRIV.ROLE_ID   AS SYSTEM_ROLE_ID,
21                      AS ENTITY_TYP_CODE,
(
    SELECT
        SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID
    FROM
        SEC_NN_SERVER_T
    WHERE
        UPPER(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%') ) AS ENTITY_ID
FROM
    SEC_USER_PRIV,
    SEC_USER
WHERE
    SEC_USER.USR_ID = SEC_USER_PRIV.USR_ID
AND ((
            SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_TYP_CODE = 21
        AND SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_ID IN (
            (
                SELECT
                    SERVER_T.SRV_ID
                FROM
                    SERVER_T
                WHERE
                    UPPER(SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%') ))))
```

Please assist thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By repeating the subquery from your where clause in your select you destroy the coupling between SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_ID and the subquery. Subqueries in the SELECT part should always return only one value, because the select constructs the row to be returned. I expect your problem will be solved by simply including SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_ID instead of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

What part of the error message do you not understand?  Your subquery is returning more than one row.  You can fix the error by using `rownum` or aggregation:

```
(SELECT MAX(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID)
 FROM SEC_NN_SERVER_T
 WHERE UPPER(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%')
) as ENTITY_ID
```

or perhaps:

```
(SELECT LISTAGG(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID)
 FROM SEC_NN_SERVER_T
 WHERE UPPER(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%')
) as ENTITY_IDS
```

However, this might not be what you really want.  You need to review the logic of what you are doing.

Comment: I've considered using LISTAGG but that does not fit my needs.
Same for MAX, as it would return only one of the existing IDs.

Comment: @DavidFaiz . . . You should ask another question, providing sample data, desired results, and the logic you want your query to implement.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SEC_USER.USR_ID         AS USR_ID,
SEC_USER.USR_FIRST_NAME AS USR_FIRST_NAME,
SEC_USER.USR_LAST_NAME  AS USR_LAST_NAME,
SEC_USER_PRIV.ROLE_ID   AS SYSTEM_ROLE_ID,
21 AS ENTITY_TYP_CODE,
SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID AS ENTITY_ID
FROM SEC_USER_PRIV inner join
     SEC_USER on SEC_USER.USR_ID = SEC_USER_PRIV.USR_ID inner join
     SERVER_T on SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_ID = SERVER_T.SRV_ID 
             and UPPER(SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE '%GEN%'
where SEC_USER_PRIV.ENTITY_TYP_CODE = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments on above answers, and guessing as it is not clear what you want to do, you might like to investigate cursors. A generic example below.

```
Declare

  cursor c_test is 
  SELECT SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_ID
  FROM   SEC_NN_SERVER_T
  WHERE  UPPER(SEC_NN_SERVER_T.SRV_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%gen%') ) AS ENTITY_ID

begin

  for v_row in c_test loop

     your logic for each ID here.

  end loop;

end;
```